# CodeIgniter and modal forms(populating)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Usually with PHP and editing you click on a link that goes to a separate PHP page that has the "ID" of the entry you want to edit, you get the ID and populate your form base on this.

I would like to know how to do this if I am using a modal form? How do I get the ID get the records associated with it then populate the modal form.

sort of like this

```
//dropdown behavior for resp task and sub_task
$('#r_task_id').change(function() {
    var selected_task_id = $('#r_task_id').val();
    $.post("Assignment/populateSubTaskDropDown", { 'selected_task_id' : selected_task_id },//$_POST['selected_task_id']
             function(data){                
            $('#r_sub_task_id').empty();
            $.each(data, function(val, text) {
                $('#r_sub_task_id').append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
                );
     });}, "json");

});//task
```

PHP code is:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('selected_sub_task_id', $this->input->post('selected_sub_task_id'));
    $json_resp_user = $this->assignmentModel->getResponsibleUsers($this->session->userdata('selected_sub_task_id'));

    $json = array();
    $json[0] = "-Select-";

    if( count($json_resp_user) >= 1 ){ //if there is more in the result than the -Select-
        foreach($json_resp_user as $detail){
            //$json[$detail->user_id] = $detail->first_name." ".$detail->middle_name." ".$detail->last_name;
            $json[$detail->user_id] = $detail->first_name." ".$detail->last_name;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

but for the whole form not just a dropdown.

Comment: You can create a "partial" view that contains simply your form element.

Comment: can you please be more specific on what you mean by partial view?

Comment: A partial view, is essentially a View that only contains the form and it's inputs. Your main view that the form currently sits in can then include this partial and using Javascript/Ajax, you can call an action that returns your partial form only. Then you can simply replace it with the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick read of $.post() of jQuery and apparently that was what I meant =p

the part on your script with

> id ='' //Set this when opening the modal window

was where I was stuck on how to read that.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

sorry if I wasn't clear but thank you for taking the time and trouble to answer me.

Answer (score 1):

When you open the modal window set the id of the record in a public javascript variable, and on submit of the modal form pass the id parameter through url.

Another way is to have a hidden variable inside the form in the modal window and set it with the while opening the modal window. So it will be get passed the update form on the modal window is submitted.

```
<script>
    id ='' //Set this when opening the modal window
    function appendId(myform)
    {
        myform.action = myform.action + "/" + id;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<div id='modalWindow'>
    <form onsubmit='return appendId(this)'>
        //other elements
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but how do you pass that variable to php and populate the form?

Comment: I have updated with the code. Please check.. You can get the id in the form parameter. If you don't want to have parameter set the id to some hidden field inside the form instead of updating the action.